# Creating new variable by aggregation in python 2

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, aggregate

I have data on births that looks like this:

```
Date    Country  Sex
1.1.20  USA      M
1.1.20  USA      M
1.1.20  Italy    F
1.1.20  England  M
2.1.20  Italy    F
2.1.20  Italy    M
3.1.20  USA      F
3.1.20  USA      F
```

My purpose is to get a new dataframe in which each row is a date at a country, and then number of total births, number of male births and number of female births. It's supposed to look like this:

```
Date    Country Births Males Females
1.1.20  USA     2      2     0
1.1.20  Italy   1      0     1
1.1.20  England 1      1     0
2.1.20  Italy   2      1     1
3.1.20  USA     2      0     2
```

I tried using this code:

```
df.groupby(by=['Date', 'Country', 'Sex']).size()
```

but it only gave me a new column of total births, with different rows for each sex in every date+country combination.

any help will be appreciated.

Thanks,
Eran

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `group` the dataframe on columns `Date` and `Country` then aggregate column `Sex` using `value_counts` followed by `unstack` to reshape, finally `assign` the `Births` columns by summing frequency along `axis=1`:

```
out = df.groupby(['Date', 'Country'], sort=False)['Sex']\
                    .value_counts().unstack(fill_value=0)

out.assign(Births=out.sum(1)).reset_index()\
   .rename(columns={'M': 'Male', 'F': 'Female'})
```

Or you can use a very similar approach with [`.crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) instead of `groupby` + `value_counts`:

```
out = pd.crosstab([df['Date'], df['Country']], df['Sex'], colnames=[None])

out.assign(Births=out.sum(1)).reset_index()\
   .rename(columns={'M': 'Male', 'F': 'Female'})
```

---

```
     Date  Country  Female  Male  Births
0  1.1.20      USA       0     2       2
1  1.1.20    Italy       1     0       1
2  1.1.20  England       0     1       1
3  2.1.20    Italy       1     1       2
4  3.1.20      USA       2     0       2
```